# can't get past AWS Elastic Beanstalk "Congratulations" screen when launching Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I followed all of [the directions](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html) and [this](http://passagebank-env-ky692euhv5.elasticbeanstalk.com) is [the result](http://snapplr.com/pph8).

I'm in the process of creating the .rvmrc file at my application root path, as well as the `setup_load_paths.rb`  file in my `/config` folder [as described here](http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/the-path-to-better-rvm-and-passenger-integration). I did all that, and then I realized my computer is using ruby 1.9.3p194. While the EC instances is using 1.9.3p286. So I'm in the process of matching them up and re-creating the .rvmrc file.

While doing that, I noticed that the beanstalk ec2 server doesn't even have rails installed. I should be able to type `rails --version` I assume and see the version like I can on my computer and with `ruby --version` on the server. So I'm installing RVM, with and rails ([as I've done in the past](https://rvm.io/rvm/install))  on my new beanstalk ec2 server. But in general, it seems this all defeats the purpose. It's supposed to be somewhat automatic. Installing rails definitely doesn't sound right. Was it installed another way on the server?

Any advice on how to get the new beanstalk support for ROR working? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

From the error in your passenger exception it looks like Bundler was unable to locate the `Ascii85` gem in your remote sources. Your remote source should be listed in your Gemfile at the top line in the form:

```
source :rubygems
```

If this is not working, try specifying the source explicitly in the form:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Note that you should not be doing anything special for RVM/Passenger integration in a deploy. In fact, any extra specialized integration may actually cause problems with Elastic Beanstalk if any platform details change. You should be building your application using standard Rails conventions.

As far as `rails -v` failing: Rails is brought in via your Gemfile, which relies on `bundle install` succeeding. Your passenger error shows that Bundler failed to resolve your dependencies against your remote sources, which likely means that Rails was also not installed. In other words, Rails will only be available if the bundle installation succeeds.